# Why do I get differently styled menus in different applications?

Tags: themes, menu

I have been using elementary OS for a while and I have noticed there is slight difference in the styles of different Apps. For example the menu in Firefox is like this :

[image: Firefox Menu screenshot]

*Note: - I have configured the icons to show with entries*

Whereas the menu of the Files (`pantheon-files`) looks like this : -

[image: Files menu screenshot]

How and why is this difference?

Is it possible to have the Files styled menu in Firefox? Why not?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem you're noticing is that some 3rd party apps use different [*widget toolkits*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Widget_toolkit). In a nutshell, the toolkit is the component that contains the instructions for how certain interface elements should look and behave.

All elementary apps use the Gtk+ 3 toolkit. Firefox uses a toolkit called XUL. By default, it tries to imitate the look of the older Gtk+ 2, which is still used by some popular apps like Gimp.

While I'm sure it's probably possibly to apply themes to Firefox to make it imitate Gtk+ 3, you should be aware that there will most likely be inherent inconsistencies from using a different toolkit.

Comment: That addon is currently unmaintained. There was a post by its developer posted in the Google+ community three or four weeks ago in which he announced that it's currently unsupported. Maybe [this tutorial](https://github.com/chpii/Headerbar) would be more helpful?

Comment: @r3bl That's for GNOME, not elementary. There might just not be anything then